# How should I define interfaces of documents when using Typescript and Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, typescript

Consider a simple user collection:

```
// db.ts
export interface User {
      _id: mongodb.ObjectId;
      username: string;
      password: string;
      somethingElse: string;
}

// user.ts
import {User} from "../db"
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    // user._id is a mongodb.Object.
    const user: User = await db.getUser(id);

    res.send(user);
});

// index.ts
// code that will runs on browser
import {User} from "../../db"
$.get('/user/...').done((user: User) => {
    // user._id is string.
    console.log(user._id);
});
```

It works perfectly until I want to use this interface in client codes. Because the `_id` of user becomes a hex string when tranmitted as json from server. If I set `_id` to be `mongodb.ObjectId | string`, the behavior gets wierd.
[image]

Comment: I think you should try this : [ObjectId.valueOf](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/#ObjectId.valueOf)

Comment: Do you mean I should use `valueOf` instead of `toHexString`? That's not my problem. I am wondering why `_id` loses all methods when it is of an union type. @Bameza

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to separate them in a smart way :

```
interface User {
   username: string;
   password: string;
   somethingElse: string;
}

export interface UserJSON extends User {
   _id : string
}

export interface UserDB extends User {
   _id : mongodb.ObjectId
}
```

and later take either UserJSON ( client ) or UserDB ( server-side ).

Comment: Using generics and `type` is better. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @drinchev. And I have figured out a better way to do it, using generics:

```
interface User<IdType> {
    _id: IdType;
    username: string;
    posts: Post<IdType>[];
}

interface Post<IdType> {
    _id: IdType;
    text: string;
}

export type UserDB = User<mongodb.ObjectID>;
```

Comment: It's opinionated, but anyway at one point you might want to add more methods to your database user, which don't exist in your JSON schema. So in my projects I usually choose to have two separate interfaces

Comment: I use it mainly for interacting with database, so the interface is likely to be a plain object. If necessary, I will create a class that extends it. Is your project open source? I would like to see it.@drinchev

Comment: I'm using sequelize, not mongodb ... I'm contributing to the typings of sequelize. More interestingly the tests show how to use them https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/sequelize/sequelize-tests.ts and they have the basic idea.